# PHP session echo checkbox and radio buttons

Tags: php, forms, variables, echo

I am trying to echo checkbox names, however I am unable to echo the name of the checkbox as all that appears is a '1' if the checkbox or radio button has been checked.

Does anyone know how I can change my code so that if the user selects that they are a vegetarian and allergic to peanut, "Vegetarian, Peanut Allergy" is displayed on my page instead of the number "1" for each checked item.

I would also prefer the cost of sitting in the VIP area to be echoed as apposed to "Yes" or "No".

Here is my the relevant code for the checkboxes and radio buttons on my reservations page:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
     $_SESSION['vege'] = isset($_POST['vege']);
}

 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
     $_SESSION['vegan'] = isset($_POST['vegan']);
}

 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
     $_SESSION['peanut'] = isset($_POST['peanut']);
}

 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
     $_SESSION['gluten'] = isset($_POST['gluten']);
}

 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
     $_SESSION['vip'] = isset($_POST['vip']);
}
?>
...
<strong>Dietary Requirements:</strong>
 Vegetarian <input type="checkbox" name="vege" value="Vegetarian" <?php if(isset($_POST['vege'])) echo "checked='checked'"; ?>>
 Vegan <input type="checkbox" name="vegan" value="Vegan" <?php if(isset($_POST['vegan'])) echo "checked='checked'"; ?>>
 Peanut Allergy <input type="checkbox" name="peanut" value="Peanut Allergy" <?php if(isset($_POST['peanut'])) echo "checked='checked'"; ?>>
 Gluten Allergy <input type="checkbox" name="gluten" value="Gluten Allergy" <?php if(isset($_POST['gluten'])) echo "checked='checked'"; ?>>

<strong> VIP area* : </strong> <br><br>
 Yes (+£5) <input type="radio" name="vip" <?php if (isset($vip) && $vip=="Yes") echo "checked";?> value="Yes">
 <br><span id="vip" class="error"><?php echo $vipErr;?></span><br>
 No <input type="radio" name="vip" <?php if (isset($vip) && $vip=="No") echo "checked";?> value="No">
```

Here is the php I am currently using which echos "1" when the user makes a selection on my thank you page:

```
<b>Dietary Requirements: </b><?php echo $_SESSION['vege'];?><?php echo $_SESSION['vegan'];?><?php echo $_SESSION['peanut'];?><?php echo $_SESSION['gluten'];?>
<b>VIP Area Costs: </b>£<?php echo $_SESSION['vip'];?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You assigned not the value to the session array! Because you used isset() as a assignment! And then you assigned 1 because isset returned 1, because they are set!

So try this:

```
<?php

    session_start();

    if ( !empty($_POST['vege']) ) 
         $_SESSION['vege'] = $_POST['vege'];

     if ( !empty($_POST['vegan'])) 
         $_SESSION['vegan'] = $_POST['vegan'];

     if ( !empty($_POST['peanut'])) 
         $_SESSION['peanut'] = $_POST['peanut'];    

     if ( !empty($_POST['gluten'])) 
         $_SESSION['gluten'] = $_POST['gluten'];

     if ( !empty($_POST['vip'])) 
         $_SESSION['vip'] = $_POST['vip'];


?>
```

Edit:

If you echo session index check if they are set like this:

```
    <b>Dietary Requirements: </b>
    <?php 

        if(isset($_SESSION['vege']))
            echo $_SESSION['vege'];

        if(isset($_SESSION['vegan']))
            echo $_SESSION['vegan'];

        if(isset($_SESSION['peanut']))
            echo $_SESSION['peanut'];

        if(isset($_SESSION['gluten']))
            echo $_SESSION['gluten'];


    ?>
    <b>VIP Area Costs: </b>£<?php if(isset($_SESSION['vip'])) echo $_SESSION['vip'];?>
```

Comment: This works okay, however if I click submit with no checkboxes checked then I get an error on my screen after form validation because no selection has been made. Is there a way to bypass this? Thanks for your suggestion regardless

Comment: Please post the error! Also the html form would be nice ;D

Comment: @JamesPatterson Check if the session index isset before you echo it!

Comment: Works great, is there a way I can add a comma and space between each dietary requirement? Also I wish the VIP area cost to be echoed, e.g. "5" if the user selects "Yes". Is this possible? Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @JamesPatterson Yes just append this  . ", " to the echo statement! And for the ViP just echo 5 if it is set!

Comment: I have tried to append this to the echo statement however it affects if the user only chooses one checkbox, how can I make this conditional to show only if multiple boxes have been checked? Also I am not sure as to how to echo 5 if VIP is checked as I am new to web languages :( Can you show me a working example please?

Answer (score 0):

Basically your error is displaying boolean from isset() function.
if you want to echo value just use
`$_SESSION['vegan'] = isset($_POST['vegan']) ? $_POST['vegan']:"";`

what does the code mean?
`$x = $trueOrFalse ? $valueIfTrue : $valueIfFalse;`

of course **perform** some **sanitizing**:
 `$_SESSION['vegan']  = htmlspecialchars($_POST['vegan']);`

**NEVER EVER ECHO PURE USER INPUT!** Always sanitize! By not sanitizing user input you allow custom external scripts to easily be run as any HTML tag can be injected into the page such as `<script>`

Why are you checking your `POST['submit']` variable 5 times?
You only need to check it once.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
    $_SESSION['vege']    = isset($_POST['vege'])   ? $_POST['vege'];
    $_SESSION['vegan']   = isset($_POST['vegan'])  ? $_POST['vegan'];
    $_SESSION['peanut']  = isset($_POST['peanut']) ? $_POST['peanut'];
    $_SESSION['gluten']  = isset($_POST['gluten']) ? $_POST['gluten'];
    $_SESSION['vip']     = isset($_POST['vip'])    ? $_POST['vip'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have implemented your suggestion but it just throws an error up stating there is an undefined index on my reservation page when opened

Comment: I've added an edit, it may need to be reviewed. You'll see my fix will fix your problem. But basically you're trying to echo a variable that is not set, because now you're not checking if it isset()

Comment: Do this instead `$_SESSION['vegan'] = isset($_POST['vegan']) ? $_POST['vegan']:"";`